# Autotools AM_CPPFLAGS (and others) ignored?

Tags: autotools

My company keeps certain header files and libraries in non-standard (but not changing) location.

I'm trying to add the header path to the build.  If I define the environment variable CPPFLAGS, I can add header search paths, and the headers are found.  But all attempts to set the search path from within configure.ac or src/Makefile.am have failed.

In src/Makefile.am I have tried

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I/path/to/headers
```

But the headers are not found.  I've tried to set CPPFLAGS in configure.ac and Makefile.am, and that doesn't work.  I've tried

```
AC_SUBST(CPPFLAGS, ['-I/path/to/headers'])
```

with and without the single quotes, also no luck

I've tried in src/Makefile.am

```
main_CPPFLAGS = -I/path/to/headers
```

I'd rather not have to set an environment variable.  That would require an extra instruction and extra step to the build sequence (and documentation).  Any idea what I am missing?

**Addendum**

I neglected to mention that I'm cross-compiling on MacOS for an ARM host (not iOS).

Here's a sanitized version of src/Makefile.am.  It's got several of the possibilities in it at the moment.  None of them get the -I flag to the compiler.  Setting the CPPFLAGS environment variable *does* get the -I flag to the compiler.

```
SUBDIRS = .
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = first.h second.h   main.cpp
main_LDADD = -lone  -ltwo 
main_CPPFLAGS =  -I/path/to/headers
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I/path/to/headers
INCLUDES = -I/path/to/headers
```

Comment: Your `AM_CPPFLAGS = -I/path/to/headers` is correct, it should pass that -I option to your compiler. The only reason I can think of that it doesn't is when either your automake version is very old, or because something with the cross compiling causes it to behave different from what I'm used to (I didn't use autotools for cross compiling yet).

Answer (score 0):

If the build system is supposed to be public, do not hardcode the path in your `Makefile.am`.

If instead it's an internal build the solution you want is

```
INCLUDES = -Ipath/to/headers
```

Comment: Completely internal.  Standard locations for us, internally.  Unfortunately, this didn't work if placed in src/Makefile.am.  Is that the place you intended?  I should have mentioned (editing question) that I'm cross-compiling on MacOS for ARM (not iOS). I might try building on Linux in a VirtualBox.

Comment: Ah that does change things, `INCLUDES` is meant to work, but I"m not sure what the compiler would be doing. Can you see if the `-I$path` is passed at all to the compiler? If not that's quite strange. Can you provide a (properly name-censored) sample of `Makefile.am`?

Comment: The included path does not appear in the call to the compiler.  However, if I set an environment variable, it *does* appear.  I'll post Makefile.am

Comment: As far as I can see that all should work. Are you re-executing `autoreconf` after making your change?

Comment: Yes, I am re-executing autoreconf.  There must be something strange about my situation.  For now I'll move ahead with an environment variable, but I'll hope for an answer here.  Note that AC_SUBST() also did not work.  Shouldn't that have set the environment variable?  Is there a way to set an environment variable from the configure.ac script?

Comment: `AC_SUBST()` does not set the environment variable but rather replace it in the `Makefile.in`, so that can be overridden. I do find it strange it's not honouring `INCLUDES` though, as that's definitely what it's designed for. The only thing that is strange in your `Makefile.am` is `SUBDIRS = .` which should not be needed...

Answer (score 0):

I can't put a quote in a comment... so lemme add this here. Your Makefile.am should officially look like this:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I/path/to/headers
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = first.h second.h main.cpp
main_LDADD = -lone -ltwo
```

where I moved AM_CPPFLAGS to the top and removed the SUBDIRS '.', because those things hurt my eyes.